# heroku: route subdirectory to a second node.js app?

Tags: node.js, heroku, express

I have a heroku node.js app running under the domain foo.com. I want to proxy all urls beginning with foo.com/bar/ to a second node.js process - but I want the process to be controlled within the same heroku app. Is this possible?

If not, is it possible to proxy a subdirectory to a second heroku app? I haven't been able to find much control over how to do routing outside of the web app's entry point. That is, I can easily control routing within node.js using Express for example, but that doesn't let me proxy to a different app.

My last resort is simply using a subdomain instead of a subdirectory, but I'd like to see if a subdirectory is possible first. Thanks!

Edit: I had to solve my problem using http-proxy. I have two express servers listening on different ports and then a third externally facing server that routes to either of the two depending on the url. Not ideal of course, but I couldn't get anything else to work. The wrap-app2 approach described below had some url issues that I couldn't figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new express server and put a middleware in the main one to redirect to the secondary when comes a request to your desired path:

```
  var app2 = express();

  app2.use(function(req, res){
      res.send('Hey, I\'m another express server');
  });

  app.use('/foo', app2);
```

I haven't tried it yet in Heroku, but it the same process and doesn't create any new TCP binding or process, so It will work. For reference, [a modified plain express template](https://gist.github.com/brunoduran/8614569#file-gistfile1-js-L31-L37).

And if you *really* want other express process handling the connection, you need to use cluster. Check the [worker.send utility](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_worker_send_message_sendhandle).

```
  app.use('/foo', function(req,res){
        //You can send req too if you want.
        worker.send('foo', res);
  });
```

Comment: This didn't actually work due to some strange behavior with the path being duplicated when it is handled by app2. Can't remember exactly the behavior, but app2 would see a url like '/foo/foo/...' instead of just '/foo/...'.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. The most elegant way I could think is by using clustering. 1 Heroku Dyno contains four cores. Therefore, you can run four worker threads to a node process.

Here is an [introduction to clustering](https://nadeesha.silvrback.com/setting-up-multiple-worker-threads-for-your-node-server).

What you're looking at is initializing two express `app`s (assuming you're using express) and serving those two in two worker threads.

```
if (cluster.isMaster) {
    //  let's make four child processes
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (i%2 == 0) {
           cluster.fork(envForApp1);
        } else {
           cluster.fork(envForApp2);
        }
    }
} else {
    // refer to NODE_ENV and see whether this should be your app1 or app2
    // which should be started. This is passed from the fork() before.

    app.listen(8080);
}
```